# Does it matter when we use the preventDefault method?

Tags: javascript, methods, preventdefault

Does it matter when we use the preventDefault method? (right in the beginning of a function vs at the end). All the tutorials that I have watched place preventDefault at the end of the function, but I would assume the first thing you want to do is prevent the default behavior. I have noticed that it works if it's at the beginning of the function and it works at the very end of the function:

```
function calculateResults(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    //UI Vars
    const amount = document.querySelector(`#amount`);
    const interest = document.querySelector(`#interest`);
    const years = document.querySelector(`#years`);
    const monthlyPayment = document.querySelector(`#monthly-payment`);
    const totalPayment = document.querySelector(`#total-payment`);
    const totalInterest =document.querySelector(`#total-interest`);

    const princapal =  parseFloat(amount.value);
    const calculatedInterest = parseFloat(interest.value)/100/12;
    const calculatedPayment = parseFloat(years.value) * 12;

    // compute monthly payments
    const x = Math.pow(1 + calculatedInterest, calculatedPayment);

}
```

VS

```
function calculateResults(e){

    //UI Vars
    const amount = document.querySelector(`#amount`);
    const interest = document.querySelector(`#interest`);
    const years = document.querySelector(`#years`);
    const monthlyPayment = document.querySelector(`#monthly-payment`);
    const totalPayment = document.querySelector(`#total-payment`);
    const totalInterest =document.querySelector(`#total-interest`);

    const princapal =  parseFloat(amount.value);
    const calculatedInterest = parseFloat(interest.value)/100/12;
    const calculatedPayment = parseFloat(years.value) * 12;

    // compute monthly payments
    const x = Math.pow(1 + calculatedInterest, calculatedPayment);

    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I guess my main concern is if I have a lot going on in the function is it possible that the browser will do its default behavior before it gets to preventDefault at the end? Or will it wait to do everything in the function before it attempts to do its default behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best practice is to call it as soon as possible.

If any error is thrown within the code before it reaches the `preventDefault` it may not get called and browser will perform the default action.

Once it is called however if an error is thrown after that the default action won't occur

Answer (score 1):

There are situations where you won't always want to use `e.preventDefault`, which implies that where you call it within a function doesn't really matter.

Here is some [example code from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```
function checkName(evt) {
  var charCode = evt.charCode;
  if (charCode != 0) {
    if (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      displayWarning(
        "Please use lowercase letters only."
        + "\n" + "charCode: " + charCode + "\n"
      );
    }
  }
}
```

That said, I myself usually call it at the beginning if I absolutely intend to prevent the default action.

Answer (score 0):

Calling preventDefault() during any stage of event flow cancels the event, meaning that any default action normally taken by the implementation as a result of the event will not occur. [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

It do matter

Work as it expected

```
function checkName(evt) { 
  var charCode = evt.charCode;
  if (charCode != 0) {
   if (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122) {
     evt.preventDefault();
     displayWarning(
      "Please use lowercase letters only."
      + "\n" + "charCode: " + charCode + "\n"
    );
  }
 }
}
```

It will cancel all the event action "if you type a letter it won't work" //only change the evt.preventDefault from place

```
function checkName(evt) { 
 evt.preventDefault();
  var charCode = evt.charCode;
  if (charCode != 0) {
   if (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122) {
    displayWarning(
     "Please use lowercase letters only."
     + "\n" + "charCode: " + charCode + "\n"
    );
   }
  }
}
```

example [codePen](https://codepen.io/erodriguezfeliz/pen/wyBmEx)